# Google colab remove permanent file

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

[image]

I have this permanent non empty directory named "sample_data" that isn't deleting even after deleting it during one session. If I do factory reset it comes back.
Is there a way to delete this directory permanently?

Answer (score 0):

The permanent non empty directory `sample_data/` (present in `/content/`) is a directory containing sample datasets that come **default** in all `run times`. These sample datasets help the first timers to learn without worrying about where to get the datasets. So, even if you delete the `sample_data/` directory and `factory reset` the runtime it comes back.

But I find that, if you delete it once in a `run time` you are working, it doesn't come back until you do a `factory reset`. Although there is no guaranty that every time your code will be executed with the same `run time` and it (`sample_data/` dir) can be present.

So, I would not worry about it, but if you are still fixated on deleting it. Maybe you can use `show/hide code` in `menu view` with below code.

```
#@title Initial setup...
!rm -rf sample_data/
```

[image: view in jupyter for above code]